# Getting an iterator for traversing a binary tree using depth first

Tags: python, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I want to do a depth first traversal of a binary tree using a for loop and perform calculations at each step.

Lets say you have a tree of 4 levels:

```
       root
       /  \
      /    \
     /      \
    xx       xx
   /  \     /  \
  /    \   /    \
xx    xx   xx    xx
/ \   / \  / \   / \
x  x x   x x  x  x  x
```

If you put the "steps of the depth first exploration of the  tree" in a list it would look like this:

```
[
[1],
[1,1], 
[1,1,1],
[1,1,0],
[1,0],
[1,0,1],
[1,0,0],
[0], 
[0,1],
[0,1,0], 
[0,1,1],
[0,0],
[0,0,1]
[0,0,0] 
]
```

Is there a function that given the levels of a binary tree returns the "steps of the tree exploration" in a list?

My first though was to use the `itertools.permutation`library but it doesn't give you the right order.

I also tried using:

```
l = [False, True]
list(itertools.product(l, repeat=3))
```

Close but it doesn't take into account that I'm going up and down the levels of the tree.

Comment: please explain the contents of your "tree Exploration list"  I understand a 1 = visited & 0 indicates not visited, but how do the positions relate to the traversal?

Comment: @itprorh66 for example: [1,1,0] indicates left on first level, left on second, and right on third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your binary tree is a *perfect* binary tree, you could use this function:

```
def traverse(height, left=1, right=0):
    path = []
    while True:
        if len(path) < height:
            path.append(left)
        else:
            while path[-1] == right:
                path.pop()
                if not path:
                    return
            path[-1] = right
        yield path
```

Then call it as follows for a tree with height 3:

```
for path in traverse(3):
    print(path)
```